# Gulp watch all files but render only one (sass)

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I want to make `gulp` watch for all changes on my work folders but to generate only one file. Because I use `scss` which imports all required files, there is no need to compile all `.css` files, only main one.

Now, my `gulpfile.js` contains:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var util    = require('gulp-util');
var sass    = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/style.scss')
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

And I have to go in `./sass/style.scss` and save it to triger gulp watch.

I want gulp to watch all files (something like `./**/*.scss`) but to render only one - `./sass/style.scss`. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution to this is simple, just edit `watch` part of the `gulpfile.js` to:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Which says: **watch for all `.scss` and on change run `'sass'` taks**.

`'sass'` taks compiles only `./sass/style.scss'`

Answer (score 0):

No need to change anything in gulpfile.js. There is another simpler method you need only add underscore to all SCSS files that are being imported with `@import` statement (like `_*.scss`), this will forbid compiler to create separate CSS files.

Example:
`mymodular.scss` => `_mymodular.scss`

[Guidelines from SCSS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4)

> **Partials**
> You can create partial Sass files that contain little snippets of CSS that you can include in other Sass files. This is a
> great way to modularize your CSS and help keep things easier to
> maintain. A partial is a Sass file named with a leading underscore.
> You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets
> Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not
> be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the @use
> rule.