# How to organize SASS files with Gulp?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have the following Gulpfile.js: http://pastebin.com/khEF08GC

When generating the "**sass**" task, the Gulp creates .css files for each of .scss, I would like it to generate one file based only on the file "**style.scss**" which is where the **@import**.
But it happens whenever there are changes in any of the directory **_sass**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not in English.

Comment: Olá. Este site está destinado a escrever em Inglês, mas não português. Por favor, re-escreve a tua pregunta em Inglês.

Comment: @Mureinik wait, I've just told him to re-write it in English. He may do.

Comment: @Mureinik everyone has their chance to make a mistake and correct it.

Comment: Sorry, I selected wrong StackOverflow on post. I'll translate, a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160997/gulp-watch-all-files-but-render-only-one-sass) solution, specifing each .scss final file and editing watch task.