# gulp if one file changes, compile the rest

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) to watch for changes
and right now I have it ignore layout files. The problem is that whenever I update a layout file, I have to change some other file for it to compile. Is there any way using gulp-watch to watch everything and then compile a part of it? I saw this [relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160997/gulp-watch-all-files-but-render-only-one-sass) but it did not use gulp-watch.

Answer (score 1):

I misread this question. I've left my original answer at the bottom for reference anyway.

---

You could use [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if).

```
 gulp.task('stream', function () {
    return gulp.src('dir/**/*.*')
        .pipe(watch('dir/**/*.*'))
        .pipe(gulpif(function (file) {
            return file.ext != ".layout"//your excluded extension
        }, processIfTrue()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

---

That link does use `gulp-watch`. In fact, as I understand, that link explains exactly what you want to do.

The `gulp-watch` and whatever task you run on change take separate `gulp.src` instances.

You can, for example, use `gulp.src('**/*.*')` for your `gulp.watch`, and then `gulp.src('**/*.less')` for your compilation task.

Comment: it uses gulps internal watcher, not gulp-watch

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that, my apologies. Perhaps [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) could help you out here?

Comment: I'll be sure to check this out when I can :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set 2 separate watchers to run, and modifying each respective file listed below in `src` would trigger the respective task for that filename:

```
$ tree -I node_modules
.
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── layout-file-1.html
    ├── layout-file-2.html
    ├── other-file-1.html
    └── other-file-2.html

1 directory, 6 files
```

## gulpfile.js - `gulp.watch()` function

```
var gulp = require('gulp')

// files with the word "layout" in them
var layoutFiles = 'src/**/*layout*';

// files without the word "layout" in them
var otherFiles = ['src/**/*', '!'+layoutFiles];

// these tasks will show as completed in console output
gulp.task('build-layout-files');
gulp.task('build-other-files');

gulp.task('watch', function(cb) {
   // watch only layoutFiles
   gulp.watch(layoutFiles, ['build-layout-files']) 

   // watch only otherFiles
   gulp.watch(otherFiles, ['build-other-files']) 
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch'])
```

## gulpfile.js - `gulp-watch` module

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var watch = require('gulp-watch')

// use print to debug watch processes
var print = require('gulp-print')

// files with the word "layout" in them
var layoutFiles = 'src/**/*layout*';

// files without the word "layout" in them
var otherFiles = ['src/**/*', '!'+layoutFiles];

gulp.task('watch:layout-files', function(cb) {
   watch(layoutFiles, function () {
      gulp.src(layoutFiles)
         .pipe(print(function(fileName) {
            return "Compiling Layout File: "+fileName;
         }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('build/layout-files'))
   });
})

gulp.task('watch:other-files', function(cb) {
   watch(otherFiles, function () {
      gulp.src(otherFiles)
         .pipe(print(function(fileName) {
            return "Compiling Other File: "+fileName;
         }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('build/other-files'))
   });
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch:layout-files', 'watch:other-files'])
```

Comment: Doesn't use gulp-watch

Comment: I added `gulp-watch` code for you.  More examples here: https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/tree/master/docs